# Is it safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery, an iPad or iPhone with any USB-C port?

Tags: charging, charger

I sometimes read online that unapproved third-party chargers can cause damage (bloating, shortening the battery life, lowering the battery's maximum capacity etc) to the battery of an Apple device. That's why there's a standard of "MFi" on some chargers. Given that USB-C is a new technology and is more advanced, is it safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery, an iPad or iPhone with any USB-C port?

And as a follow-up question: is it safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery, any Apple device as long as I'm using a charger that came with an Apple device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery and device, using a standards compliant USB-C charger.

Yes, it is safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery, any Apple device with the USB-C charger that came with any other Apple device.

Ofcourse if the charger itself is damaged (i.e. you hit it with a hammer, submerge it in water, etc) - then all bets are off.

Comment: jksoegaard thank you for your answer. The follow-up question was asking if it'd be safe to charge, without causing damage to the battery, as long as I'm using "Any" charger that came with an Apple device. ie. an older charger with USB-A female port (A1357) to charge a new model iPad Pro 12.9 (A2069)

Comment: Yes, that’s just fine. An older charger is usually lower wattage, so it will take longer to take charge the device - but there’s no harm in it